# Is it a Bitmap or MetaFile?

Tags: .net, system.drawing, system.drawing.imaging

Given a `Stream` that I *know* will be a picture, is there a way to programmatically determine if it is a `Bitmap` or a `MetaFile` when pulled from `Image.FromStream(mystream)`? Like a flag or something.

Environment: .NET, System.Drawing, C#/VB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Image.RawFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.rawformat.aspx)

Comment: Brilliant, don't know how I missed that!

Answer (score 0):

I think, by reading the first few bytes one sould be able to identify. LIke `II*` are the byes in tiff file. `‰PNG`in png, `BM` in bmp files